# Разница между String() и + ''

Tags: javascript

Есть ли разница между преобразованиями в строку:

```
let a = 5;
let b = a + '';
let c = String(a);
```

Comment: В данном конкретном случае разницы нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В приведённом примере - нет. Вообще, я предпочитаю сложение со строкой - оно короче, нагляднее и работает быстрее. Кстати, есть ещё третий вариант - вызов метода `toString`, но он будет падать, если в переменной окажется `null` или `undefined`.

А вообще, разница может быть, например, с типом данных `symbol`:

```js
var num = 12345
console.log(String(num))
console.log(num.toString())
console.log(num + "")

var sym = Symbol("smth")
console.log(String(sym))
console.log(sym.toString())
console.log(sym + "")
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Answer (score 3):

Немного спецификации:

1. В случае [сложения](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation) с пустой строкой, для операнда вызывается абстрактная функция [`ToString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-tostring)
2. В случае [использования `String`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-string-constructor-string-value), без оператора `new`, если тип параметра `Symbol`, то вызовется функция [`SymbolDescriptiveString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-symboldescriptivestring), в противном случае будет вызвана та же самая [`ToString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-tostring).

---

Таким образом можно заключить, что разница будет видна только если аргументом будет объект `Symbol`.